# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserinstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. how can I fix this Error in VS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have tried to add a SQL Server database into my project as shown in the following screenshot:
[Enter image description here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfhsG.png)

How can I fix this error? I have tried everything. Even though I installed SQL Server 2019 after I found out it was not installed on my computer, it took the whole time to install and it didn't install properly.

Comment: What is your connection string? Have you actually installed SQL Server (or LocalDB if that is what you are trying to connect to)? Have you followed all the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your connect string here？ We can work together to figure it out.